# New react-native comes with Typescript template by default, and I want to init my project using pure js template

Tags: javascript, react-native

New react-native comes with Typescript template by default, and I want to init my project using pure js template. What should I do? I am using android studio emulator for testing.

Comment: Not possible, but you can use javascript in a project, take a look at this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript.

Answer (score 1):

react native higher than 0.70 version will give you TS template.

you should use spesific lower version (0.70 or lower) in order to get the plain JS template.

like this:

```
$ npx react-native@0.70 init AwesomeProject --version 0.70
```

Comment: This defeats the purspose a bit. You can't just go and tell people to use older versions of the software, they'll be stuck there forever? This seems counter-useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement, and just as user18309290's answer, this can not be done right now. For I, just ignore the typed things, and changed App.tsx to App.js (should be jsx?). Maybe someone likes to fire an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Comment: Hello, I solved it from installing the old version of react native 0.70.

`npx react-native@0.70.0 init AwesomeProject --version 0.70.0`

Comment: This worked for me!  I think you should propose it as an answer.  Any idea why https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript lists the current version of reactnative as 0.71, but `react-native -v` returns
`10.1.3`?